# How can I scrape a website that does not show any HTML codes in the source using Python without Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web, web-scraping

I would like to scrape a website that does not have any HTML codes in the page source using Python.

I have tried doing it with Selenium but I am trying to do it without Selenium as I have some difficulties importing this function to my Rasperry Pi.

https://www.cea.gov.sg/aceas/public-register/sales/1?page=1&pageSize=10&sortAscFlag=true&sort=name&registrationNumber=R

This is something that I am interested in scraping but I can't seem to do it effectively. I have tried using bs4 and requests to work with it, but there's no HTML codes for me to work with and I can't seem to find other libraries that can do it without Selenium.

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.cea.gov.sg/aceas/public-register/sales/1?page=1&pageSize=10&sortAscFlag=true&sort=name&registrationNumber=R')
print(r.text)
```

This is a simplified version of what I have tried before.

```
D:\Codes\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:/Codes/requests_test.py 
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=en><head><meta charset=utf-8><meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><meta name=description content="The Council for Estate Agencies is the government agency that regulates Singaporeâs real estate agency industry."><link rel=icon href=/aceas/assets/common/favicon.ico><title>ACEAS</title><script src=https://assets.wogaa.sg/scripts/wogaa.js></script><script>(function(w, d, s, l, i) {
        w[l] = w[l] || [];
        w[l].push({ "gtm.start": new Date().getTime(), event: "gtm.js" });
        var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
          j = d.createElement(s),
          dl = l != "dataLayer" ? "&l=" + l : "";
        j.async = true;
        j.src = "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=" + i + dl;
        f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
      })(window, document, "script", "dataLayer", "GTM-53ZNG4N");</script><link rel=preload as=style href=/aceas/assets/comp/vendor-style.css><link rel=stylesheet href=/aceas/assets/comp/vendor-style.css><link rel=preload as=style href=/aceas/assets/comp/index.css><link rel=stylesheet href=/aceas/assets/comp/index.css><link rel=preload as=style href=/aceas/assets/comp/formBase-minified.css><link rel=stylesheet href=/aceas/assets/comp/formBase-minified.css><link rel=preload as=style href=/aceas/assets/comp/rteComp.css><link rel=stylesheet href=/aceas/assets/comp/rteComp.css><link href=/aceas/assets/common/css/ErrorPage.css rel=prefetch><link href=/aceas/assets/common/css/Login.css rel=prefetch><link href=/aceas/assets/common/css/MaintenancePage.css rel=prefetch><link href=/aceas/assets/common/css/UserProfile.css rel=prefetch><link href=/aceas/assets/common/css/Workspace.css rel=prefetch><link href=/aceas/assets/common/js/ErrorPage.js rel=prefetch><link href=/aceas/assets/common/js/Login.js rel=prefetch><link href=/aceas/assets/common/js/LogoutCallback.js rel=prefetch><link href=/aceas/assets/common/js/MaintenancePage.js rel=prefetch><link href=/aceas/assets/common/js/MicroAppsContainer.js rel=prefetch><link href=/aceas/assets/common/js/OidcCallback.js rel=prefetch><link href=/aceas/assets/common/js/SilentRenewCallback.js rel=prefetch><link href=/aceas/assets/common/js/Survey.js rel=prefetch><link href=/aceas/assets/common/js/UserProfile.js rel=prefetch><link href=/aceas/assets/common/js/Workspace.js rel=prefetch><link href=/aceas/assets/common/css/index.css rel=preload as=style><link href=/aceas/assets/common/js/chunk-vendors.js rel=preload as=script><link href=/aceas/assets/common/js/index.js rel=preload as=script><link href=/aceas/assets/common/css/index.css rel=stylesheet></head><body class=xb-body><div id=common></div><noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-53ZNG4N" height=0 width=0 style=display:none;visibility:hidden></iframe></noscript><script src=/aceas/assets/common/vendor/vue@2.6.12/vue.min.js></script><script src=/aceas/assets/common/vendor/vue-router@3.4.6/vue-router.min.js></script><script src=/aceas/assets/common/vendor/vuex@3.0.1/vuex.js></script><script src=/aceas/assets/common/vendor/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js></script><script src=/aceas/assets/comp/index.js></script><script src=/aceas/assets/comp/formBase-minified.js></script><script src=/aceas/assets/comp/rteComp.js></script><script src=/aceas/assets/comp/multiStepFormWrapper.js></script><script src=/aceas/assets/common/js/chunk-vendors.js></script><script src=/aceas/assets/common/js/index.js></script></body></html>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Post your code, what have you tried until now?

Comment: I have updated the version with a simplified version of what I have tried before. The result does not show any HTML code that I can retrieve the agent's name or even get the URL for "View more details"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In hope that your next question(s) will contain a minimal reproducible example, here is one way to scrape that information: data is being hydrated into page dynamically, via XHR calls to an API. You can see that by inspecting  Dev tools - Network tab in your browser.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm

big_df = pd.DataFrame()

headers = {
    'Origin': 'https://www.cea.gov.sg',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
}

s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)
url = 'https://www.cea.gov.sg/aceas/api/internet/profile/v2/public-register/filter'

for x in tqdm(range(1, 10)):
    payload = '{"page":' + str(x) + ',"pageSize":100,"sortAscFlag":"true","registrationNumber":"R","sort":"name","profileType":2}'
    r = s.post(url, data=payload)
    df = pd.json_normalize(r.json()['data'])
    big_df = pd.concat([big_df, df], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
print(big_df)
```

This will display the datadframe in terminal:

```
id  name    businessName    licenseNumber   validityDateStart   validityDateEnd awards  disciplinaryActions registrationNumber  photoUrl    currentEa
0   0679f4a5-ca99-4c6c-a4c4-12528ece6294    'AFFAN BIN ASHAK HARI   'AFFAN A.H. L3002382K   2019-02-27T00:00:00+08:00   2022-12-31T23:59:59.99+08:00    None    None    R060832J    None    ERA REALTY NETWORK PTE LTD
1   c55b6be6-15fa-490c-a688-745a91839596    AARON BAN QI WEI    AARON BAN   L3002382K   2019-08-30T00:00:00+08:00   2022-12-31T23:59:59.99+08:00    None    None    R061593I    None    ERA REALTY NETWORK PTE LTD
2   6525dc35-5d0b-467f-8fc1-68894884e3fb    AARON GOH JIN HAO   None    L3008022J   2019-09-16T00:00:00+08:00   2022-12-31T19:14:00+08:00   None    None    R052117I    None    PROPNEX REALTY PTE. LTD.
3   38d64cfc-5cb2-4027-9add-f01ee4ed8769    AARON HUAN SHEN LI  AARON HUAN  L3008022J   2019-01-01T00:00:00+08:00   2022-12-31T14:57:00+08:00   None    None    R041988I    None    PROPNEX REALTY PTE. LTD.
4   15aa903c-2402-4bed-87d2-ef6fce88a502    AARON LEONG JIA SHENG   None    L3008022J   2021-01-01T00:00:00+08:00   2022-12-31T23:59:59.99+08:00    None    None    R062835F    None    PROPNEX REALTY PTE. LTD.
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
895 d845c8a7-0713-40ba-b0d9-7f06933997ee    ANG YAM NEE, AGNES JAEL JAEL ANG    L3002382K   2017-08-28T00:00:00+08:00   2022-12-31T20:14:00+08:00   None    None    R058715C    None    ERA REALTY NETWORK PTE LTD
896 705a51a0-2024-4fc3-9a84-27530a579681    ANG YAN BRYAN ANG   L3008022J   2018-02-27T00:00:00+08:00   2022-12-31T23:59:59.99+08:00    None    None    R009088G    None    PROPNEX REALTY PTE. LTD.
897 968a17a8-b0bb-455f-a95b-0281084d1da5    ANG YANG MING   ANG YM  L3008022J   2011-01-01T00:00:00+08:00   2022-12-31T20:24:00+08:00   None    None    R009471H    None    PROPNEX REALTY PTE. LTD.
898 98fbdf7a-107a-4980-a7b4-82560123769e    ANG YAP CHOW    Ang Yap Chow    L3008899K   2021-04-30T00:00:00+08:00   2022-12-31T00:21:00+08:00   None    None    R063534D    None    HUTTONS ASIA PTE. LTD.
899 848efbcf-3050-4a1d-9394-bf4e8051f4a0    ANG YAP HWEE    SUNNY   L3010497H   2018-01-01T00:00:00+08:00   2022-12-31T11:44:00+08:00   None    None    R040155F    None    ASSET PROPERTY PRIVATE LIMITED
```

There are 341 pages, and you can go through all, the example above is only pulling the first 10 pages of data.

Relevant pandas documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html

Requests documentation: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. This is my first few times using StackOverflow, and I definitely will try my best to provide a minimal reproducible example in the future.